# "pointer-events: none"(css) in flutter?

Tags: css, mobile, flutter

I am from the world of web development and I want to understand how to implement in the flutter "pointer-events: none". In web this property makes the element not active and does not react to the touch of the mouse and the sensor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap your widgets in an `IgnorePointer` widget:

```
IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: true,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print('pressed');
    },
    child: Text('Press me'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Odd to find "touch" events managed by `pointer` object. Fair enough.